# PhpStorm - Finding variables in template view file?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm working on a HTML template file in PhpStorm which renders some PHP variables that are set by a page controller (from which the template is then included).

I would like a list of all the variables the template page references. I know that PhpStorm can do this for class structures using the "Structure" window, but when I give focus to this template file, I can only navigate through the HTML DOM elements, not the PHP variables.

Is there any way to do this from within PhpStorm?

Comment: i am not sure that it is possible at all...

Comment: Well .. for `.php` file PhpStorm can show HTML and PHP tabs in Structure view .. but ordinary variables are not shown in Structure even for pure PHP files (especially when it's usage-only).